# R - Shiny - map isn't displayed when I use tablePanel

Tags: r, shiny

My ui.R is :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

navbarPage("POC IoT",

  tabPanel("Carte Géolocalisation",

    #tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")    

  ),

  tabPanel("Carte Trajet"),

  tabPanel("Données")

)
```

My server.R is :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet) 
source("load_data.R")

data <- load_data_moment()

function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet(data) %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(~long, ~lat,clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),popup = ~paste(remorque))

  })

}
```

When I use this code without tabPanel, it works, I have a map.
When I add the tabPanel, I have the navbar but map isn't displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is the `height = "100%"` parameter in the `leafletOutput`. Because at the moment this is 100% of nothing which is nothing.

Either remove this or change it from `%` to `px` or add `style = "height:500px;"` as an argument to the tabPanel containing the map like this.

```
navbarPage("POC IoT",
           tabPanel("tab1",

                    #tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
                    style = "height:92vh;",
                    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")    

           ),
           tabPanel("Carte Trajet",
                    uiOutput("some1")),
           tabPanel("Données",
                    uiOutput("some12"))       

)
```

`92vh` is a css unit meaning more or less 92% of the screen which is what is left after taking away room for the header.
Hope this helps!

Comment: With 92vh the menu bar is displayed but not the map. I don't understand why.

Comment: Which browser are you using? vh is quit a new unit and might not be supported by all browsers. If it doesn't work just change it to 500px or something like that.

Comment: Thats it !! It works on IE and Google Chrome. But I was testing with the Rstudio viewer. And it didn't work with it.